# .\Obj\stm32_gpio_demo.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol mf_wordwrap (referred from render_bmp.o)

Tags: arm

I am trying to compile using ARM stm32f10x , but I'm getting this error

```
**Rebuild target 'Final_STM_Thermal'
assembling startup_stm32f10x_hd.s...
compiling main.c...    
..\User\defs.h(15): warning:  #1295-D: Deprecated declaration ADC_GetValue - give arg types
compiling stm32f10x_it.c...    
compiling GPIO_Config.c...
..\User\defs.h(15): warning:  #1295-D: Deprecated declaration ADC_GetValue - give arg types
compiling Printer.c...
..\User\defs.h(15): warning:  #1295-D: Deprecated declaration ADC_GetValue - give arg types
..\User\Printer.c(472): warning:  #177-D: variable "length" was declared but never referenced
..\User\Printer.c(472): warning:  #177-D: variable "x" was declared but never referenced
..\User\Printer.c(473): warning:  #177-D: variable "maxsize" was declared but never referenced
compiling render_bmp.c...
..\User\mf_font.h(135): warning:  #1295-D: Deprecated declaration mf_get_font_list - give arg types
..\User\mf_kerning.h(27): warning:  #1-D: last line of file ends without a newline
..\User\render_bmp.c(98): warning:  #9-D: nested comment is not allowed
..\User\render_bmp.c(48): warning:  #177-D: variable "usage_text" was declared but never referenced
..\User\render_bmp.c(59): warning:  #177-D: function "parse_options" was declared but never referenced
..\User\render_bmp.c(222): warning:  #177-D: function "character_callback" was declared but never referenced
compiling mf_encoding.c...
compiling mf_font.c...
..\User\mf_font.h(135): warning:  #1295-D: Deprecated declaration mf_get_font_list - give arg types
compiling mf_rlefont.c...
..\User\mf_font.h(135): warning:  #1295-D: Deprecated declaration mf_get_font_list - give arg types
compiling core_cm3.c...
compiling system_stm32f10x.c...
compiling misc.c...
compiling stm32f10x_gpio.c...
compiling stm32f10x_rcc.c...
compiling stm32f10x_usart.c...
compiling stm32f10x_adc.c...
linking...
**.\Obj\stm32_gpio_demo.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol mf_scale_font (referred from render_bmp.o).**
**.\Obj\stm32_gpio_demo.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol mf_wordwrap (referred from render_bmp.o).**
Target not created**
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the mf_scale_font and mf_wordwrap are part of uGFX library and these files are missing on your setup.

Are you sure you have the dependencies installed?

`sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev:i386 build-essential gcc-multilib`

As per the official documentation [Linux uGFX Wiki](https://wiki.ugfx.io/index.php/Linux)

You will also need to set: `CFLAGS = sdl2-config --libs --cflags` for the SDL to link properly.